# Write a DLL to use in Lotusscript

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2015, lotusscript

I've written a DLL that I can access in a test VB application using the code below:

```
Imports SKC.SKC
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim folder As String = "C:\ChemicalStructures\"
        Dim file As String = "FA40151.skc"
        Dim SKC As New SKC.SKC
        Dim result As Boolean = SKC.updateSKC(folder, file)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I've also written a Lotusscript agent with the following code:

```
Declare Function updateSKC Lib "C:\Users\Phil\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SKC\SKC\bin\x86\Debug\SKC.dll" Alias "updateSKC" (ByVal folder As String, file As String) As Boolean

Sub Initialize
    Dim folder As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim result As Boolean
    folder = "C:\ChemicalStructures"
    file = "FA40324.skc"
    If updateSKC(file, folder) Then Print "Hey Phil, it worked !!"
End Sub
```

The first one works, the second one throws an error "External function not found".
I'm a Lotusscript programmer, and this is the first DLL I've written.  I'm using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2015. I presume that it's something to do with how I've declared the function in the DLL, meaning that I have to access the class first, or something like that.  Like I say, I've very new Visual Studio and DLL writing, and everything I know is self-taught over the last couple of weeks!

```
Public Function updateSKC(ByVal folderName As String, ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean
```

Comment: Take a look at [«How to access .Net classes from LotusScript»](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230705) topic.

Comment: I just found that page too. That's solved one problem, now I have a mixed-assembly problem for my class library, and unfortunately the app.config route won't work for a class library.

Comment: Can you elaborate on both parts of that? What problem did you solve and how and how? (By calling CreateObject("SKC.SKC"?) And what is your new problem?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Sorry for being so vague, yesterday was a horrible day all round.  By using gacutil and regasm I installed SKC.SKC so that I could call them using COM.
Now I have the problem that one of the DLLs I've referenced uses the 2.0 framework.  For an executable I'd use "<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">" in app.config, but class libraries do not have use app.config.
I think I've found another solution here - http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/  but it's in C#, so I just need to convert it.

Comment: Gotcha. Interesting problem. I assume that finding a version of that dependent DLL that was built for .NET 4 (or finding the source code so you can build it that way yourself) is not an option.